# Why is the xlsxwriter not updating Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to replace a set of placeholder texts in an excel sheet which follows the following syntax:

```
{{text_to_replace}}
```

For example cell A1 could hold this value;

```
"We are looking for {{item_placeholder}}"
```

I then have a dictionary of replacements: For example

```
{'item_placeholder': "apples, 'location_placeholder': "UK"}
```

So I want the text replaced to look like this:

```
"We are looking for apples"
```

There is also the chance that two placeholders need to be replaced in the same cell, for example;

```
"We are looking for {{item_placeholder}} in the {{location_placeholder}}
```

This is how the sheet looks before iterating:
[image: sheet before parsing]

This is the expected output:

[image: sheet with placeholder swapped out]

So I've written code to iterate over each cell (I know there has been a lot of discussion on here about the best way to iterate over the rows but in the end I went for itertuples), however the data frame is not being updated with the new value.

```
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

for row in df.itertuples():
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        cell_value = df.iloc[row.Index][col_num]
        for var_name, replacement in variables.items():
            if str(replacement):
                if type(cell_value) == str and "{{" + var_name + "}}" in cell_value:
                    cell_value = str(cell_value).replace("{{" + var_name + "}}", str(replacement))
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'"replacement" in dict is mandatory. Missing for {var_name}')
        if type(cell_value) == str:
            worksheet.write(row.Index, col_num, cell_value)

workbook.close()
```

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamentally basic but I'm new to Panda's and Python and have consulted the docs for xlsxwriter [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_data.html) which leads me to think it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just reading the spreadsheet, and then rewriting it to a file. I know this isn't what you are specifically asking, but I use the same loop you do and this works. it might be that in your code you just need use `str(var_name)` instead of just `var_name`. Just guessing as you don't say if there's an error or just doesn't update.

Anywho, here are two example where you can read the file, operate on a single column, and another where you operate on the entire dataframe.

Create simple .xlsx file with this data, and sheetname is 'a'

```
this    {{item_placeholder}} in the {{location_placeholder}}    a   test    to  find    {{item_placeholder}}
this    is  a   test    to  find    {{item_placeholder}}
this    is  {{item_placeholder}}    test    to  find    {{item_placeholder}} in the {{location_placeholder}}
```

**Option 1**

```
replacement = {'item_placeholder': "apples", 'location_placeholder': "UK"}
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None, sheet_name =['a'])['a']

for k, v in replacement.items():
    # print(k,v)
    df.iloc[:, 6] = df.iloc[:, 6].str.replace('{{' + str(k) + '}}', v)
print(df)

      0                                                  1                     2     3   4     5                 6
0  this  {{item_placeholder}} in the {{location_placeho...                     a  test  to  find            apples
1  this                                                 is                     a  test  to  find            apples
2  this                                                 is  {{item_placeholder}}  test  to  find  apples in the UK
```

**Option 2**

```
replacement = {'item_placeholder': "apples", 'location_placeholder': "UK"}
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', header=None, sheet_name =['a'])['a']

for k, v in replacement.items():
    # print(k,v)
    df = df.replace('{{' + str(k) + '}}', v, regex=True)
print(df)

      0                 1       2     3   4     5                 6
0  this  apples in the UK       a  test  to  find            apples
1  this                is       a  test  to  find            apples
2  this                is  apples  test  to  find  apples in the UK
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leon, option 2 worked for me and was a lot cleaner than what I was proposing :)
Out of interest I'd love to know why the other way wasn't working. 
So to answer your question above, I'm not receiving any error when writing and the value of cell_value when writing to worksheet is 'test  to  find  apples in the UK' for example but the df is not updating. This is part of a util class I'm creating for others to utilise when creating excel sheets in the future so the reading of the excel is done in another funciton

Comment: Glad it worked. As for your data frame you never update the data frame anywhere in your loops. Just cell_value is updated and written to excel. If you really want to update the date frame you may want to look closely at your variables.